# Maximum likelihood estimation of (complicated) custom pdf in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability

I have a (sadly not straightforward) probability density function which depends on four parameters p1, p2, p3, p4 and contains function such as erf, sqrt, ...

Is there a general way to compute MLE estimates using Python? I know I can inherit from stats.rv_continuous (see below) but in this case I need to redefine the fit() function and I have no analytical formula for MLE estimates...

I would rather avoid optimization-based method if possible.

```
class custom_distrib(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _init_(self, p1, p2, p3, p4):
        super(custom_distrib, self)._init_()
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3
        self.p4 = p4

    def _pdf(self, x):
        res = compute_my_custom_distrib(x, self.p1, self.p2, self.p3, self.p4)
        return res
```

Comment: *"I have no analytical formula for MLE estimates"* but *"I would rather avoid optimization-based method if possible."*   In that case, could you say more about other methods that you think might work?

Comment: You don't have to redefine `fit()`, but the default function uses a numerical optimization method.

Comment: I edit my post to add my current class code for my custom pdf. If I use fit(), it will yield p1, p2, p3 and p4 estimates. For your first question, indeed there is only two solutions: analytical expression or optimization-based methods.